# Hyperlinks onclick function not working

Tags: jquery, html

I need to handle a onlick function on hyperlinks but its not working..

HTML Code:-

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateParent()" id="2" value="2">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function updateParent(control) {
                    alert('Hi')
                }

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbnBy/1/

Comment: Since you are using jquery anyway... Why don't you use the .click() event? --> http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 6):

`updateParent` only exists inside the `.ready()` function.  It needs to be global for `onclick` to work.

Also, you shouldn't be using inline events.  You have jQuery, use that.

```
<a href="#" id="2" value="2">CLICK HERE</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#2').click(function(e){
            // preventDefault... it prevents the "default" action of the tag
            // In this case, it would try to nagivate to `#`.  Which would
            // scroll the page to the top.
            e.preventDefault();

            alert('hi');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer, perhaps add the purpose behind e.PreventDefault() as the person asking the question looks new to jQuery.

Comment: @AlexKey: I added a comment in the code block.  How's that? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `function` should be in global scope for `onclick` to work.

Remove everything except the function:

```
function updateParent(control) {
  alert('Hi')
}
```

But the above would still not work as JsFiddle creates a closure.

So the final solution would be just:

```
window.updateParent = function(control){
   alert("hi");
}
```

Also you don't need inline js. Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#2').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action such as redirecting.
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Also you can change the jsfiddle option to use *wrap in head*

Comment: You *can* change jsFiddle's settings.  Just change `onload` to `no wrap, <head>`.